# Referencing a slot in an array of objects that is initialized to null

Tags: java, debugging, generics, iterator, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to check to see if an array's slot is equal to null, for the purposes of iterating through a hash table. I'm getting a NullPointerException, however. Is there any way to get around this?

Thanks!

Here's the next() method (and its class) that are causing the problem.

```
 public K next() throws NoSuchElementException{
      int tempStore = -1;
      MapHashCellList tempCells = null;
      System.out.println("Got here! 1");
      System.out.println(mapCells);
      if(mapCells.length==0) {throw new NoSuchElementException();}
      if (mapCells[arrayPointer]!=null && listCounter<=mapCells[arrayPointer].size()-2){
              System.out.println("Got here! 2");
        tempCells = mapCells[arrayPointer];
        tempStore = listCounter;
        listCounter++;
      }
      else{
        arrayPointer++;
              System.out.println("Got here! 3");
        while (mapCells[arrayPointer]==null){
          arrayPointer++;
          listCounter=0;
                System.out.println("Got here! 4");
          if(mapCells[arrayPointer]!=null){
            tempCells = mapCells[arrayPointer];
            tempStore = listCounter;
            listCounter++;
          }
          System.out.println("ListCounter: " + listCounter);
          System.out.println("Array: " + arrayPointer);
        }
      }
      return (K)tempCells.get(tempStore).getKey();
    }
```

Per one of the user's questions, here is the entire class' code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ProjectMap<K,V> implements MapInterface<K,V>{

  public MapHashCellList[] mapCells;
  public int size;

  public ProjectMap(){
    mapCells = new MapHashCellList[11];
    size = 0;
  }

  public boolean containsKey( K key ){
    if(key==null){return false;}
    if(isEmpty()){return false;}
    if(mapCells[hashValue(key)]!=null){
      MapHashCellList temp = (MapHashCellList)mapCells[hashValue(key)];
      for (int g =0; g<temp.size(); g++){
        if (temp.get(g).getKey().equals(key)){
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty(){
    if(size==0){return true;}
    else return false;
  }


  public int hashValue(K key){
    return (int)(Math.abs(key.hashCode()%10));
  }

  public MapHashCellList get(int index){
    return (MapHashCellList)mapCells[index];
  }

  public V get( K key ){
    if(mapCells[hashValue(key)]!=null){
      MapHashCellList temp = (MapHashCellList)mapCells[hashValue(key)];
      for (int q =0; q<temp.size(); q++){
        if (temp.get(q).getKey().equals(key)){
          return (V)temp.get(q).getValue();
        }
      }

    }
    return null;
  }

  //Key = docID, V = documentNumber
  public V put( K key, V value ){
    //If cell isn't empty and Key exists, replace existing Value since duplicate
    if(mapCells[hashValue(key)]!=null){
      MapHashCellList temp = (MapHashCellList)mapCells[hashValue(key)];
      for (int q =0; q<temp.size(); q++){
        if (temp.get(q).getKey().equals(key)){
          V temp1 = (V)temp.get(q).getValue();
          temp.get(q).setValue(value);
          return temp1;
        }
      }
    }

    //Otherwise add to end of linkedlist
    if(mapCells[hashValue(key)]!=null){
      MapHashCellList temp = (MapHashCellList)mapCells[hashValue(key)];
      MapHashCell newCell = new MapHashCell(key,value);
      temp.add(newCell);
      size++;
      return null;
    }


    //Index doesn't exist yet, so make new LinkedList and add to correct index position
    MapHashCellList newCell = new MapHashCellList(key,value);
    mapCells[hashValue(key)] = newCell;
    size++;
    return null;
  }


  public V remove( K key ){
    if(mapCells[hashValue(key)]!=null){
      MapHashCellList temp = (MapHashCellList)mapCells[hashValue(key)];
      for (int q =0; q<temp.size(); q++){
        if (temp.get(q).getKey().equals(key)){
          V temp1 = (V)temp.get(q).getValue();
          temp.remove(q);
          size--;
          return temp1;
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public int size(){
    return size;
  }

  public Iterator<K> iterator(){
    Iterator<K> temp = new KIterator();
    return temp;
  }

  private class KIterator implements Iterator<K>{
    int arrayPointer=0;
    int listCounter=0;

    KIterator(){
    }


    public K next() throws NoSuchElementException{
      int tempStore = -1;
      MapHashCellList tempCells = null;
      System.out.println("Got here! 1");
      System.out.println(mapCells);
      if(mapCells.length==0) {throw new NoSuchElementException();}
      if (mapCells[arrayPointer]!=null && listCounter<=mapCells[arrayPointer].size()-2){
              System.out.println("Got here! 2");
        tempCells = mapCells[arrayPointer];
        tempStore = listCounter;
        listCounter++;
      }
      else{
        arrayPointer++;
              System.out.println("Got here! 3");
        while (mapCells[arrayPointer]==null){
          arrayPointer++;
          listCounter=0;
                System.out.println("Got here! 4");
          if(mapCells[arrayPointer]!=null){
            tempCells = mapCells[arrayPointer];
            tempStore = listCounter;
            listCounter++;
          }
          System.out.println("ListCounter: " + listCounter);
          System.out.println("Array: " + arrayPointer);
        }
      }
      return (K)tempCells.get(tempStore).getKey();
    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
      if(isEmpty()) {return false;}
      for(int d=arrayPointer; d<mapCells.length; d++){
        if (mapCells[d]!=null){
          try{
            if(mapCells[d].get(listCounter+1)!=null){
              return true;
            }
          }
          catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            for(int l=arrayPointer; l<mapCells.length; l++){
              if (mapCells[l]!=null){
                return true;
              }
              else{
                return false;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    //Removes last element
    public void remove(){
      mapCells[arrayPointer].remove(listCounter-1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `mapCells`?

Comment: The line that appears to be causing the problem is "while (mapCells[arrayPointer]==null)"...is there another way to get around this error?

Comment: The class is a subclass, mapCells is initialized in the "parent" class.

Comment: I can post the whole class it that would be helpful, just didn't want to flood you guys with code! :)

Comment: My guess is that MapCells is null at this point.

Comment: @JesanFafon MapCells at index arrayPointer is null, that's what i'm trying to check. Should I be initializing it to something else?

Comment: This is ***way too much code***, and is still incomplete -- where's `MapHashCellList `?  You should be using an IDE debugger, such as Eclipse or NetBeans, to set a NPE breakpoint so you can trace through the code and determine the exact cause of the problem.

Comment: The question is whether `mapCells` is null or `mapCells[index]` is null.  We can't tell from the code you've provided.

Comment: `while (mapCells[arrayPointer]==null){
          System.out.println("Second loop: "+mapCells[arrayPointer].size());`. You have a logical problem there.

Comment: @BheshGurung That's just a print statement for debugging purposes

Comment: That is how you end up with an NPE.

Comment: @JimGarrison sorry! I'm new to java and I'm not entirely sure what your comment means (admittedly naive...). Could you explain?

Comment: @MakMak Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: @LouisWasserman mapCells[index] is null

Comment: Step through your code in your development environment. You can set a breakpoint that stops your program at the point where the exception occurs, and then examine variable values to see what's wrong.

Comment: It seems that the issue is that i'm referencing mapCells[index] which is known to be null. is there another way to check if this is null that won't throw a NPE?

Comment: After `System.out.println("Got here! 1");` add `System.out.println(mapCells);`.  This is obviously not a fix but just a troubleshooting step.

Comment: @PM77-1 It printed out "[LMapHashCellList;@3979c7cf"

Comment: Can you please post your entire exception message with full trace back.  Want to make sure that you pinpointed the right offending line of code.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ProjectMap$KIterator.next(ProjectMap.java:149)

Comment: That's all my IDE is giving me...

Comment: while (mapCells[arrayPointer]==null){
          System.out.println("Second loop: "+mapCells[arrayPointer].size());

}

will yield a null pointer. You just confirmed MapCells[pointer] is null and you're now asking for its size.

Comment: @JesanFafon When I remove that line I still have the same problem.

Comment: At the same line? Then as I said, mapCells is probably null. Add a couple debug statements before entering the loop.

Print the value of mapCells and also print the value of arrayPointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one of the problems is with your `public K next` method:

```
public K next() throws NoSuchElementException{
  int tempStore = -1;
  MapHashCellList tempCells = null;
  System.out.println("Got here! 1");
  System.out.println(mapCells);
  if(mapCells.length==0) {throw new NoSuchElementException();}
  if (mapCells[arrayPointer]!=null && listCounter<=mapCells[arrayPointer].size()-2){
          System.out.println("Got here! 2");
    tempCells = mapCells[arrayPointer];
    tempStore = listCounter;
    listCounter++;
  }
  else{
    arrayPointer++;
          System.out.println("Got here! 3");
    while (mapCells[arrayPointer]==null){
      arrayPointer++;
      listCounter=0;
            System.out.println("Got here! 4");
      if(mapCells[arrayPointer]!=null){
        tempCells = mapCells[arrayPointer];
        tempStore = listCounter;
        listCounter++;
      }
      System.out.println("ListCounter: " + listCounter);
      System.out.println("Array: " + arrayPointer);
    }
  }
  return (K)tempCells.get(tempStore).getKey();
}
```

In the beginning:

```
MapHashCellList tempCells = null;
```

Then look at the `else` part.  You have the following loop:

```
while (mapCells[arrayPointer]==null){
```

Inside this loop you have this:

```
if(mapCells[arrayPointer]!=null){
        tempCells = mapCells[arrayPointer];
        tempStore = listCounter;
        ..................
```

Since the program would **never** get inside this `if` (your `while` condition guarantees it), `tempCells` remains **null**.

And then, at the very end you have the following:

```
return (K)tempCells.get(tempStore).getKey();
```

which has to produce `NullPointerException`.